# Ajax php GET method not working?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to validate captcha through ajax but its only giving me invalid captcha message ?

here is my ajax

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){

      $('#submitcap').click(function(){

         $.post("report.php", $("#formcap").serialize(),  function(response) {
            $('#error').html(response);
         });
         return false;

      });
   });
</script>
```

here is my html

```
<span id="error"></span>
<form method="GET" id="formcap">
   <img src="<?php echo $baseUrl; ?>/captcha/captcha.php" id="captcha" /><br/>

   <!-- CHANGE TEXT LINK -->
   <a href="#" onclick="
    document.getElementById('captcha').src='<?php echo $baseUrl; ?>/captcha/captcha.php?'+Math.random();
    document.getElementById('captcha-form').focus();"
    id="change-image">Not readable? Change text.</a><br/><br/>

   <input type="text" name="captcha" id="captcha-form" style="width:100px" autocomplete="off" /><br/>
   <input type="submit" id="submitcap"/>
</form>
```

Here is my PHP file

```
<?php
   /** Validate captcha */
   if (!empty($_REQUEST['captcha'])) {
      if (empty($_SESSION['captcha']) || trim(strtolower($_REQUEST['captcha'])) !=$_SESSION['captcha']) {
         $captcha_message = "Invalid captcha";
         $style = "background-color: #FF606C";
      } else {
         $captcha_message = "Valid captcha";
         $style = "background-color: #CCFF99";
      }

      $request_captcha = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['captcha']);

      echo <<<HTML
      <div id="result" style="$style">
          <h2>$captcha_message</h2>
          <table>
          <tr>
             <td>Session CAPTCHA:</td>
             <td>{$_SESSION['captcha']}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Form CAPTCHA:</td>
             <td>$request_captcha</td>
          </tr>
       </table>
     </div>
HTML;
     unset($_SESSION['captcha']);
   }
?>
```

I dont know why i am getting Invalid captcha message If i validate this captcha without ajax it works fine

Comment: What did you tried? SO is not a debug tool.

Comment: You know difference between `post` and `get`, don't you?

Comment: what do you mean by what i tried ? thats the code what i tried

Comment: @Leri yes I know but i dont know how to use get method in AJAX :(

Comment: @YousafEhsan You are not using xhr directly here. You're using some kind of wrapper around it (more likely `jQuery`). So look at the docs of that library. If it's jQuery [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) it is. Anyway, -1 for no research.

Comment: Nicely formatted code. Well done.

Comment: @Leri please dont say that if i did research or not.. I was searching a simple GET method with one variable to request but i couldnt found even a one clear example.. thats not my fault there are alot of crap on internet thats why i asked here... And so rude for -1

Comment: @YousafEhsan If you think that documentation of library you're using is crap, you should not be using it. And debug your code, please. You don't have minimal understanding of your problem.

Comment: I asked the question if my code is wrong ? IF you see something wrong than why you cant correct it ? if you cant then why you are -1 my question ? I didnt said that the documentation is crap.. i said info on internet about get method in ajax is not for begginers is crap

Comment: @YousafEhsan When I was absolute beginner and realized tutorials were crap and even if they were not they don't give much. Downloaded bunch of books and started learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what the others are getting at is that you have used $_REQUEST when you should be using $_POST, as you are POSTing data to this form by virtue of using the jQuery .post function.

What you need to do is debug the PHP code that is recieving the posted data. I admit that can seem a little daunting to a beginner, but here is a suggestion.
Because you cannot echo data out of that code to the screen try writing it to a file for you to check after each execution like this.

```
<?php
  /** Validate captcha */

  // show whats actually in the session file as this point
  file_put_contents( 'captcha.log', 'SESSION ' . print_r($_SESSION, TRUE) );   

  // show what you passed to the script
  file_put_contents( 'captcha.log', 'POST ' . print_r($_POST, TRUE), FILE_APPEND );  

  /*
   * Now you can edit the captcha.log file which will be in the same directory as this script
   */


  if (!empty($_POST['captcha'])) {
     if (empty($_SESSION['captcha']) || trim(strtolower($_POST['captcha'])) != $_SESSION['captcha']) {
        $captcha_message = "Invalid captcha";
        $style = "background-color: #FF606C";
     } else {
        $captcha_message = "Valid captcha";
        $style = "background-color: #CCFF99";
     }

....
```

This should allow you to check what the 2 values $_POST['captcha'] and $_SESSION['captcha'] are before you run the  `!=` test.

For reference the $_REQUEST array is an amalgamation of the $_POST and $_GET array, so while its not exactly wrong to use it in certain situations it does open up your code to being abused as it is much easier to try and hack it by simply calling it using a querystring like `www.site.tld/script_name.php?captcha=aaa`. Which will create a $_GET array with $_GET['captcha'] = 'aaa' and therefore a $_REQUEST array with $_REQUEST['captcha'] = 'aaa'.

If your code is expecting data to be provided via a POST, like yours, and therefore loading the $_POST array its safer to use $_POST and then you will never be bothered by a hack using the querystring as you will never see it and your parameter validation will cause your script to takes the 'no data provided' exit route.

While faking posted data is a little harder, but not much.

Comment: hi thanks for the solution and only the thing that i forgot was `session_start();`  Because if we dont know whats the session captcha is how can we validate.. i m using your sugested solution.. Thanks again